# python save list to csv single quotes

Tags: python, csv

I use python(2.7) Scrapy to crawl some data ,I want to save items as a csv file,this is my code:

```
class RenthouseinfoPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.myCSV = csv.writer(open('data.csv', 'wb'))
        self.myCSV.writerow(['int', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string', 'string','array'])
        self.myCSV.writerow(['rentPrice','houseType','floor','rentMode','paymentType','address','telphone','imagesList'])

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.myCSV.writerow([item['rentPrice'].encode('utf-8'),item['houseType'].encode('utf-8'),item['floor'].encode('utf-8'),
                         item['rentMode'].encode('utf-8'),item['paymentType'].encode('utf-8'),item['address'].encode('utf-8'),
                         item['telphone'].encode('utf-8'),item['imagesList']])
        return item
```

open csv file I get imagesList like this:

```
"[u'/rimg_458x358/uploads/img/201507/27/e731bd0378326f57dfedbb8d9a4e9016.gif', u'/rimg_458x358/uploads/img/201507/27/0bd27344f29a6041d8e96c74e3f5d332.jpg', u'/rimg_458x358/uploads/img/201507/27/784b90acfcc0e76e34fec21b0beab5b4.jpg', u'/rimg_458x358/uploads/img/201507/27/86e9f0492c5aadbe75dca31e4d2b17a1.jpg', u'/rimg_458x358/uploads/img/201507/27/e381583d26b9f9cf6dda84fe5378837e.jpg']"
```

but the Server can't accept this format! how can I get：single quotes to double quotes,and no prefix 'u' ?like this:

```
"["/rimg_458x358/uploads/img/201507/27/e731bd0378326f57dfedbb8d9a4e9016.gif", "/rimg_458x358/uploads/img/201507/27/0bd27344f29a6041d8e96c74e3f5d332.jpg", "/rimg_458x358/uploads/img/201507/27/784b90acfcc0e76e34fec21b0beab5b4.jpg", "/rimg_458x358/uploads/img/201507/27/86e9f0492c5aadbe75dca31e4d2b17a1.jpg", "/rimg_458x358/uploads/img/201507/27/e381583d26b9f9cf6dda84fe5378837e.jpg"]"
```

the progrom have no error,I only want to change the format!I just upload csv file to Server by a Webpage not pass by program

Comment: Please add the output of `print(item)` from inside `process_item(...)`

Comment: You never close the open file handle from `open('data.csv', ...)`. This might be a cause of  your problem

Comment: There is no problem with your code. Show the sever code please.

Comment: Also show the code, where you are passing the data to server.

Comment: Please provide the shortest possible **complete** program that demonstrates the error. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your defaults are changed some where.

Try Using this for the the writer:

```
    self.CSV = csv.writer(open('data.csv', 'wb'), delimiter = ',' , quotchar = """ )
```

That should work, but have not tested.

Comment: have some errors I use `self.CSV = csv.writer(open('data.csv', 'wb'), delimiter = ',' , quotechar = ' " ' )` ,but no use